# Select multiple data columns in function

Tags: r

How can I select for multiple existing columns from a dataframe when I index my function with the triple dots as a parameter?

for example:

```
devTest <- function(data,...){
  col = list(...)
  innerTest <- function(...){
    more = list(...)
    data %>% select(more)
  }
  x <- innerTest({{col}})
  x
}
devTest(mtcars,mpg, gear)
```

produces this error:

> Error in devTest(mtcars, vs) : object 'vs' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you need to defuse the arguments using `enquos` (since you want to pass column *symbols* rather than strings to `devText`):

```r
devTest <- function(data, ...) {
    col <- enquos(...)
    innerTest <- function(col) {
        data %>% select(!!!col)
    }
    innerTest(col)
}
devTest(mtcars,mpg, gear)
```

Other minor issues are the duplicate `list(...)` calls which are not necessary, as we can define `innerTest` to take a `list` of quosures directly (which we can then evaluate using the triple-bang operator `!!!`).