# Store dplyr method in function and return outside

Tags: r

Inspired by my previous post: [Select multiple data columns in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74001374/select-multiple-data-columns-in-function), I wanted to store a single `dplyr` method inside a function, and then call it outside the function. Exactly like the following -

```
devTest <- function(data, ...) {
  col <- enquos(...)
  
  innerTest <- function(col) {
    return(select(!!!col))
  }
  data %>% innerTest(col)
}
devTest(mtcars,mpg, gear)
```

However, I get this error:

> Error in innerTest(., col) : unused argument (col)

Comment: What pipes do is turn `data %>% innerTest(col)` into `innerTest(data, col)`. The way you've defined `innerTest` it only takes 1 argument, but the way you're calling it you are giving it 2.

Comment: @GregorThomas This explanation helped! So I just needed to include `data`, return `data %>% select(!!!col)` inside the function also. I have spent hours trying to figure this out! I thought the data outside the function would overlap with that inside

Comment: Objects inside `devTest()` will also be available inside `innerTest()` -- this isn't about what what objects are accessible in the environments, this is purely syntax. `a %>% foo()` is the same as `foo(a)`. `a %>% foo(b)` is the same as `foo(a, b)`. That's all the pipe does. If you write a function `foo()` that takes exactly one argument, then `a %>% foo(b)` is an error, because it's giving 2 arguments to a function that expects 1 argument.

Comment: @Gregor your explanation has been very helpful for my upcoming projects which work on nesting functions.