# Passing outer function params to inner function

Tags: r, dplyr

Following on from my previous challenging exercise: [promise already under evaluation with nesting from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74004632/promise-already-under-evaluation-with-nesting-from-function), I have learnt thus far how to properly use: `enquos, !!!, c()` within a function for a variety of calling methods. However, my next challenge is more complex - I want to call a function within a function, and only passing it parameters from the outer function. Essentially, I wanted to make a list of functions and pass different parameters to each element from the list by using another function.

for example:

```
anotherTest <- function(data,...){
  cols = enquos(...)
  
  testFunc <- function(df, more){
   df %>% mutate(!!!c(more))
  }
  n <- length(cols)
  addMutation <- replicate(n, testFunc, simplify=FALSE)
  print(addMutation)
  addCars <- replicate(n, data)
  mapply(function(x, y, z) x %>% reduce(., y, z),addCars, addMutation, cols)
}
```

When I call:

```
anotherTest(mtcars, vs, gear, am)
```

I get this error:

> Error in fn(out, elt, ...) : unused argument (~vs)

Comment: What does the argument `more` do in testFunc? Is that correct?

Comment: @LeonSamson It is supposed to mutate additional columns when we add the parameter `cols` into `testFunc`

Comment: I think your error comes from 1) not specifying `simplify = FALSE` when using `replicate` on your `data`, and 2) using `reduce` inside the `mapply`. It's not even clear to me what you are attempting to do with `reduce` here. Could you please explain what the expected output of your function is?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, the `simplify` did help solve the problem and having `reduce` was not optimal. I did try what `akrun` did but with `mapply` however, without the `simplify=FALSE` It always produced an error. Unfortunately, the error was not helpful to identity was caused it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could try

```
anotherTest <- function(data,...){
  cols = enquos(...)
  
  testFunc <- function(df, more){
   df %>% mutate(!!!c(more))
  }
  n <- length(cols)
  addMutation <- replicate(n, testFunc, simplify=FALSE)
 
  addCars <- replicate(n, data, simplify = FALSE)

Map(function(x, y, z) y(x, z), addCars, addMutation, cols)
}
```

-testing

```
out <- anotherTest(mtcars, vs, gear, am)
> lapply(out, head, 3)
[[1]]
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1

[[2]]
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1

[[3]]
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Comment: I have a question on this - How can I recursively apply `y(x,z)` on a single dataframe? Because `Map` returns a separate list for each additional parameter i.e. for `vs, gear, am`. Is there a way to iterate in place following the function above?

Comment: For example, I have tried: ```map2_dfc(addCar, addMutation, ~ .y(.x, cols))``` however, this only extends the lists as an extra tibble, rather than applying it in the same dataframe.

Comment: @DollarX `Map` applies the function to each element of the list.  If you want to recursively apply you could use a for loop instead of the `Map` i.e. `out <- addMutation[[1]](addCars[[1]], cols[[1]])
   for(i in 2:length(addCars)) {
     out <- addMutation[[i]](out, cols[[i]]);
   }
   out}`